# How to pop back to root ViewController from viewController that was used?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller that shows a view controller programmatically. Now I am trying to go back to the root view controller of the navigation controller if there is an error, but I can't seem to get back there.

The page I'm working with is presented thusly:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: page)
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

And if I try go back duly:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

I get a warning rudely:

> expression type UIViewController is unused

I don't want to use segues here.

Comment: Where you're calling popViewController, the same VC where you're instantiating?

Comment: check answer below. If works, please accept

Comment: Even your first comment that suppressed the warning worked great.  The conditional check is even better.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.To avoid warning use:

`_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`.

To pop back to root view controller use:-

```
if let self.navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
     navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is not a bad warning. Editor is indicating/highlighting that you are not using view controllers that are popped from navigation stack. You can ignore them if you don't want to use popped view controller

Here are some methods(function) that navigation controller providing for pop operations. They are returning optional UIViewController (intance) from it’s navigation stack, that is popped.

```
    open func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? // Returns the popped controller.

    open func popToViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? // Pops view controllers until the one specified is on top. Returns the popped controllers.

    open func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]?
```

Here is sample code, how to use it:

```
if let navigation = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
     navigation.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```